# Webpack hot dev server “cannot find module”

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

people. Currently I am learning React on Egghead.io and I find a problem importing css file in my js. This is my code in js file which importing css. The style.css is currently in the same directory. I dont know Webpack good enough to figure out how to fix that.

```
import React from 'react';
import "style.css";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '/* add your jsx here */',
      output: '',
      err: ''
    }
  }
  update(e) {
    let code = e.target.value;
    try{
      this.setState({
        output: window.Babel
                .transform(code, {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
                .code,
        err: ''
      })
    }
    catch(err) {
      this.setState({err: err.message})
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>{this.state.err}</header>
        <div className="container">
          <textarea onChange={this.update.bind(this)} 
                    defaultValue={this.state.input}/>
          <pre>
            {this.state.output}
          </pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

The text of an error is : Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/App.js Module not found: 'style.css' in C:\Front-end\projects\React\Reactapp\src

@ ./src/App.js 14:0-20

Comment: i think there is problem with import do this: import styles "./style.css"

Answer (score 0):

You imported file like this

```
import "style.css"
```

This tells Webpack to look for a module named `style.css`, the same way as it looks for `React` module imported line above

To import correcly Your styles, always use relative path to import place, which is the following

```
import "./style.css"
```